# What is the exact semantic of "from ... import" starement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I've experiment with the statement,however the result did not match the official description.
[Quotation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) is below:

> The from form uses a slightly more complex process:
>
> 1. find the module specified in the from clause, loading and initializing it if necessary;
> 2. for each of the identifiers specified in the import clauses:
>
>    1. check if the imported module has an attribute by that name
>    2. if not, attempt to import a submodule with that name and then check the imported module again for that attribute
>    3. if the attribute is not found, ImportError is raised.
>    4. otherwise, a reference to that value is stored in the local namespace, using the name in the as clause if it is present, otherwise using the attribute name

I created a namespace package named l007,  within which submodule named l009 was placed.I typed "from l007 import l009" in the interpreter, the execution was ok, while in which case a ImportError should have been raised.
Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Why do you think an ImportError should have been raised?

Comment: module l009 does not have a attribute named l009 corresponding with the official description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules):

> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. `importlib` APIs, the `import` or `import-from` statements, or built-in `__import__()`) a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object. For example, if package `spam` has a submodule `foo`, after importing `spam.foo`, `spam` will have an attribute `foo` which is bound to the submodule.

That is why the steps in your quote are in the order they are in.  Even though `l007` doesn't initially have an attribute `l009`, it will have one after the submodule import occurs.